# Generating a chart using JS libraries

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json, charts

The following set of codes are used to generate a chart using fusionchart javascript library! 
This is the php script

```
   <?php
//address of the server where db is installed
$servername = "localhost";

//username to connect to the db
//the default value is root
$username = "chart";

//password to connect to the db
//this is the value you would have specified during installation of WAMP stack
$password = "L12345d";

//name of the db under which the table is created
$dbName = "test";

//establishing the connection to the db.
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbName);

//checking if there were any error during the last connection attempt
if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

//the SQL query to be executed
$query = "SELECT * FROM top_odi_wicket_takers";

//storing the result of the executed query
$result = $conn->query($query);

//initialize the array to store the processed data
$jsonArray = array();

//check if there is any data returned by the SQL Query
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  //Converting the results into an associative array
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $jsonArrayItem = array();
    $jsonArrayItem['label'] = $row['player'];
    $jsonArrayItem['value'] = $row['wickets'];
    //append the above created object into the main array.
    array_push($jsonArray, $jsonArrayItem);
  }
}

//Closing the connection to DB
$conn->close();

//set the response content type as JSON
header('Content-type: application/json');
//output the return value of json encode using the echo function. 
echo json_encode($jsonArray);
?>
```

This is the json script

```
$(function() {
    $.ajax({

       url: 'http://localhost/GP/Charts/chart_data.php',
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(data) {
            chartData = data;
            var chartProperties = {
                "caption": "Top 10 wicket takes ODI Cricket in 2015",
                "xAxisName": "Player",
                "yAxisName": "Wickets Taken",
                "rotatevalues": "1",
                "theme": "zune"
            };

            apiChart = new FusionCharts({
                type: 'column2d',
                renderAt: 'chart-container',
                width: '550',
                height: '350',
                dataFormat: 'json',
                dataSource: {
                    "chart": chartProperties,
                    "data": chartData
                }
            });
            apiChart.render();
        }
    });
});
```

The follwoing code gives the html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Fusion Charts Column 2D Sample</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="chart-container">FusionCharts will render here</div>
  <script src="js/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
  <script src="js/fusioncharts.js"></script>
  <script src="js/fusioncharts.charts.js"></script>
  <script src="js/themes/fusioncharts.theme.zune.js"></script>
  <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

According to the tutorial i followed it should generate the chart when the html code is executed! But when its executed no chart apperas but only a text stating
"FusionCharts will render here" appears how can i correct the code inorder to generate the chart? i followed this tutorial exaclty http://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/using-with-server-side-languages/tutorials/php-mysql-charts.html

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have not installed the jquery properly. Click [here](http://jquery.com/download/) to download jquery and copy that under the above created js folder.

Answer (score 0):

```
require('http://localhost/GP/Charts/chart_data.php'')
```

should be

```
require('http://localhost/GP/Charts/chart_data.php')
```

Comment: sorry according to the tutorial it should be    url: 'http://localhost/GP/Charts/chart_data.php' but still is not working!

Comment: what do you see when you go to http://localhost/GP/Charts/chart_data.php page with your browser?

Comment: a text "fusion charts will render here" appears on the top

Comment: I am not asking about your main html file. I am asking about your chart_data.php. Is it giving you json?

Comment: yep! [{"label":"CJ Anderson","value":"25"},{"label":"Imran Tahir","value":"25"},{"label":"JH Davey","value":"21"},{"label":"M Morkel","value":"21"},{"label":"MA Starc","value":"34"},{"label":"ST Finn","value":"27"},{"label":"TA Boult","value":"36"},{"label":"TG Southee","value":"28"},{"label":"UT Yadav","value":"22"},{"label":"Wahab Riaz","value":"25"}]

Comment: Do you have any javascript error messages in your browser?

Answer (score 0):

i think u should keep all the script files inside the head tag so that they load before the dom(div) loads..give it a try

Comment: are you sure that the http call is returning some data..? try to console the reponse and check.. in this way we can find out that is it a backend problem or a frontend

Comment: no data! only the "FusionCharts will render here" text appears